# navigation menu bar cant be centrally aligned

Tags: html, css, megamenu

I am using meganizr mega menu.usually it is available either left-aligned or right-aligned.but for my requirement i tried to make it center-aligned.[Here i made an online gist.](http://dabblet.com/gist/6523499)

On the line No.35 if i remove float:left and give text-align:center to either ul or li, it will be vertical. I tried left:240px; it is in center but its not responsive. I tried solutions on other questions here for a whole day.but could not center-align menu and responsive at same time.can any one help me please?

Comment: my answer is better then jack's | 

jack's answer made menu distroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna make all menus go center add the following code to `.meganizr`

```
text-align: center;
```

then chenge following code with `.meganizr > li` class

```
.meganizr > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 37px;

    border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

demo : http://dabblet.com/gist/6524015

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I added a `<div class="wrap">` and gave it the same styles and `meganizer` then changed the width on `meganizer` to 50% (you can set it to whatever you want) and added `margin:0 auto` to it as well.

Demo:

http://dabblet.com/gist/6523922

Edit///

The `div.wrap` wraps around the menu.

Comment: thanks jack,but its not responsive anymore. the last link 'reach us' is came below the whole container,and when i resize the screen, menus are overlapping on each other.

Comment: I'll fix it. One sec.

Comment: http://dabblet.com/gist/6524296 I assumed you wanted the responsive feature to still align left. Guess since you accepted alireza's answer, you wanted it all centered. Oh well. I fixed it anyway with the responsive nav alight left.

Comment: no offense jack but with ur last solution when screen is half,menus are left aligned but the space is fully covered with black background.it will be in two column then one column.so left over empty space will look bad. whereas in ali's solution while resizing first it will be three column then two column and last one column.check it out.ur made left-aligned text into dropdown,so i will implement ur solution too.thanks for it.

Comment: pistachio, no offense, but do you not have even a rudimentary knowledge of CSS? If you don't know how to change the size of objects, take a css tutorial. If you do, why is this an issue? I had to go through all of your CSS to make sure it was responsive and not overlapping which it was doing because you had the width set at 24.9% or 34%. I'm glad it's helpful, but we're here volunteering our help, not trying to hand hold people through all their issues.

Comment: really, i dont have proper knowledge of css, Im student of electronics, i just have interest in web development. So i dont know much about it.I am trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: not having the knowledge is fine, but there are tons of tutorials online, just google it. My answer worked for centering, and it works for responsive, the issue you have is with the widths in the responsive portion. I don't know exactly what you want. You said hers gos from three to two, to one. Well hers has just as much black space on the two and one as mine, but hers is centered so it looks like less. Here's a tip, when you ask a question, be very specific, or give specific feedback of your issues. You took her second answer, but didn't give me time to fix what you didn't like.

Comment: Sorry, her smart a$$ comment pi$$ed me off.

Answer (score 1):

add `text-align: center;` to `.meganizr`

Comment: @pistachio: because in `.meganizr > li` class you have `float:left` ( remove this) and change `display: block` to `inline-block`;

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to `.meganizr`

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

demo : http://dabblet.com/gist/6523863

Comment: sorry u misunderstood i think. i want all the menus in the center,not whole container.sorry, i should have explained it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a different width (not 100%) for `.meganizer` + `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: sorry u misunderstood i think. i want all the menus in the center,not whole container.sorry, i should have explained it.